# Docker container constantly restarts when using `command` with custom script in docker-compose.yml

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently facing some issues with my Docker container setup.

What I'm trying to do is setup a MongoDB container via Dockerfile that copies, replaces the environment variables inside some configuration and script files (`.mongoshrc.js`, `mongod.conf` and `mongo-init.js`) and moves the replaced data to an output path on startup. The only file I'm not already replacing in the Dockerfile is `.mongoshrc.js` because that file is supposed to be inside the mounted `$MONGO_DATA_DIR` (/data/db) volume. So I'd have to do the replacement after the build process.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mongo:5-focal

# Set arguments and environment variables

ARG my_custom_env_variable
ENV MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE=$my_custom_env_variable

# Change user to root
USER root

# Copy .mongoshrc.js script and change permissions
COPY --chown=mongodb:mongodb ./.config/mongo/.mongoshrc.js /pre-configuration/.mongoshrc.js
RUN chmod 751 /pre-configuration/.mongoshrc.js

# Copy mongod.conf config and change permissions
COPY --chown=root:root ./.config/mongo/mongod.conf /pre-configuration/mongod.conf
RUN chmod 644 /pre-configuration/mongod.conf

# Copy mongo-init.js script and change permissions
COPY --chown=root:root ./.config/mongo/mongo-init.js /pre-configuration/mongo-init.js
RUN chmod 751 /pre-configuration/mongo-init.js

# Copy Docker Entrypoint bash script to Docker Entrypoint and change permissions
COPY --chown=root:root ./.config/docker/mongo/replace-script.sh /pre-configuration/replace-script.sh
RUN chmod 751 /pre-configuration/replace-script.sh

# Replace environment variables in mongod.conf and mongo-init.js and write to output destination
RUN /pre-configuration/replace-script.sh --input "/pre-configuration/mongod.conf" "/pre-configuration/mongo-init.js" --output "/etc/mongod.conf" "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js"

# Start MongoDB Demon with custom configuration
CMD [ "mongod", "-f", "/etc/mongod.conf" ]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    mongo:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./config/docker/mongo/Dockerfile
            args:
                my_custom_env_variable: ${MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE}
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
            - ./.logs/mongo:${MONGO_LOG_DIR}
            - ./mongo/data:${MONGO_DATA_DIR}
```

Up until now everything works perfectly. But as soon as I add a command instruction (`command: bash -c "/pre-configuration/replace-script.sh --input /pre-configuration/.mongoshrc.js --output ${MONGO_DATA_DIR}/.mongoshrc.js"`), that is supposed to replace the environment variables in `.mongoshrc.js`, to the `docker-compose.yml` the container constantly restarts without logging anything (I'm checking with `docker logs -f --tail 10 my_mongo_container`). I've tried different variations of the statement such as `command: ["/pre-configuration/replace-script.sh", "--input", "/pre-configuration/.mongoshrc.js", "--output", "${MONGO_DATA_DIR}/.mongoshrc.js"]` (as the bash script contains `#!/bin/bash`) and both variations without the variable inside the argument.

Interestingly when I start the setup with `docker-compose up -d` the container constantly restarts but the `.mongoshrc.js` inside the `$MONGO_DATA_DIR` is created.

I'm running this setup on Windows 10 (21H2), WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS; GNU/Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64) and Docker (4.9.1 81317).

Unfortunately I'm clueless as to why this happens. Any help would be appreciated!

Greetings,
fmedv

Comment: A Docker container only runs one program, and if that program exits the container exits too.  When you override the `command:` your `replace-script.sh` runs _instead of_ the MongoDB server.

Comment: So theoretically I could write an entrypoint bash script that runs both commands (replacement and daemon startup) and run that with the ```command``` instruction?

Comment: I might write an entrypoint `#!/bin/sh` script that does the setup, then ends with `exec "$@"` to run the image `CMD`.  You'd have to repeat that from the base image.

Comment: It looks like it should also work to name the scripts with file names ending in `*.sh` and put them in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, and the [`mongo` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) already has logic to execute them (see "Initializing a fresh instance" on the Docker Hub page).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still facing the same issue. I've even ommited the Dockerfile and mounted all script and config files. But as soon as I use either ```command``` or ```entrypoint``` instruction inside the ```docker-compose.yml``` the container constantly restarts. Even if I comment all the code inside the entrypoint script.